# Vuex, nuxt, localStoarage, state overwrite

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

i have question about state managment in vue/vuex

- i use 'nuxt-vuex-localstorage' for persistence
- i divided my store into modules like 'ui', 'user'

The problem is that when in one action i dispatch two store  actions like

```
const res = await API_CALL('someEndpoint')
this.$store.dispatch('ui/setSignInVisible', false)
this.$store.dispatch('customer/setToken', res.token)
```

this gives me errors because first i get  setSignInVisible to false, but this next acion set it to true.  I assume this happened because localStorage operation is async.

this solve this issue:

```
const res = await API_CALL('someEndpoint')
await this.$store.dispatch('ui/setSignInVisible', false)
this.$store.dispatch('customer/setToken', res.token)
```

But my question is, should this work this way, or there is some better approach to manage state. Approach in which i will not worry about of overriding state.

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted that comment somehow :) , because your question is really ambiguous. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the line below, you have an atomic value `false` being passed to an action or dispatch method which is presumably being used to set the value of `this.$store.state.ui.signInVisible` to `false`.

```
await this.$store.dispatch('ui/setSignInVisible', false)
```

**Mutations** in vuex are  **not allowed** to be **async**, actions are. They are not inherently async.
So for the sake of consistancy, some developers like to set all of their properties through actions even though some are synchronous in nature.
So you could call:

```
this.$store.commit('ui/setSignInInivisible', false)
```

You could also set it directry in the state `this.$store.state.ui.signInVisible = false`
Or you could try using `vuex` function `mapMutations` to put them in the methods section of your component and call them directly.
Also not sure why you would put localStorage into vuex since you can access it from everywhere.

Comment: i need localStorage for persistence